# How do we compute $50a^2\pmod{30000}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have difficulty computing the $\rm mod$ for $a ={1,2,3\ldots50}$. Is there a quick way of doing this?

Comment: The numbers are not large by any standards. I can't see this taking anymore than a two or three minutes even by hand with a calculator. Tedious maybe, but certainly not difficult. What exact difficulties are you having?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** note that $50(a+1)^2=50a^2+100a+50$

**Example:**
$50\cdot34^2\equiv27800\pmod{30000}$ so
$$
\begin{align}
50\cdot35^2
&\equiv27800+34\cdot100+50\\
&\equiv27800+3450\\
&\equiv31250\\
&\equiv1250\pmod{30000}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $x = 50a^2$, you want to find $r$ such that $50x = 30000q + r$. Then $r$ must be divisible by 50, right? Explain to yourself why that must be the case.

So try to find $a^2 \mod 600$ first. Then express $50a^2 \mod 300000$ in terms of $a^2 \mod 600$. That will help you for all $a$.

Next, notice that if $a^2 < 600$, then $a^2 \mod 600$ is just $a^2$. Use that to save work. For which $a$ do you actually have to compute something?

As the comment by @EuYu says, do the rest by hand.